# lpc1768 linker script why ram start address

Tags: cortex-m, linker-scripts

lpc1768 linker script why ram start address should be given at 0x100000C8,  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x100000C8, LENGTH = 0x7F38.

If I give at 0x10000000 then system is crashing when I enable UART interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

Your crash cause should be a providing a big clue - that offset of 0xC8 (192 bytes) is to allow space for the interrupt vector table.

Not all applications will require that the vector table be in RAM - if you have a fixed program in flash then the vector table can be there as well.  But if you are using a bootloader to run code from RAM and want that code to include interrupt service routines, you would need to place a vector table in RAM and update the register which points to it.  See for example AN10866.